# blocked:mixed-content em https chamando iframe sem https

Tags: html, google-chrome, https

Tenho um site em `https` e preciso chamar através de um `iframe` uma página em outro servidor, que infelizmente não tem `https`.
O Navegador `Chrome` bloqueia essa requisição por ser fora do https.

```
(blocked:mixed-content)
```

Existe como eu conseguir chamar essa página?

Infelizmente acho que vou fechar minha pergunta ou colocar uma própria resposta, pois é impossível fazer o que quero.

Motivo:
https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/prevent-mixed-content/fixing-mixed-content?hl=pt-br

Comment: Só hoje vi no FB sua mensagem, te adicionei lá. Vou apagar aqui.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Infelizmente acho que vou fechar minha pergunta ou colocar uma própria resposta, pois é impossível fazer o que quero.

Motivo: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/prevent-mixed-content/fixing-mixed-content?hl=pt-br

Pois o conteúdo é considerado como ativo, entrada de texto, iframe é bloqueado por todos os navegadores.